# JSON-API-Resources: How can I get the data related the specific object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

How can I fetch the data related the specific object with JSON-API-Resources.

Within controller,

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SubscriptionsController < Api::V1::ApiController

      def create
        @plan = Plan.find_by(id: plan_id_param)
        @result = Creditcard::CreateSubscription.call(@plan, params_ex: foo)

        if @result.errors.blank?
          resource = Api::V1::SubscriptionResource.new(@result, nil)
          serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(Api::V1::SubscriptionResource)
          json_body = serializer.serialize_to_hash(resource)
          render json: json_body, status: 200 # :ok
```

Usually, we can do

```
  def show
    params[:include] = "relation1.relation2.relation3" if params[:include].nil?
    super
  end
```

And it's done.
But in this case, this is `JSONAPI::SubscriptionResource` object. 
How can I show relations of the object?

Answer (score 0):

```
  resource = Api::V1::SubscriptionResource.new(@result, nil)
  serializer = JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(Api::V1::SubscriptionResource, include: ['foo_xxx.hoo_xxx'])
```

I found that, in this case you have to use `_`, instead of `-`.